# How to solve "add all in list cannot be applied to"

Tags: java, android, java-stream

I have this method:

```
filteredListIn.addAll(Stream.of(listRef)
    .filter(results ->
            results.getTitle().contains(query.toString().toLowerCase())
     ));
```

With these two variables:

```
private List<Results> listRef = new ArrayList<>();
List<Results> filteredListIn = new ArrayList<>();
```

But I'm getting

> found for addAll(Stream)
>               filteredListIn.addAll(Stream.of(listRef)
>                             ^
>       method Collection.addAll(Collection) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; Stream cannot be converted to Collection)
>       method List.addAll(Collection) is not applicable

What is the problem and how can I solve this?

Is it possible it's happening because I use external library for supporting streams under api 24?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to collect all stream elements in a list in order to add it to a collection:

```java
filteredListIn.addAll(listRef.stream()
  .filter(results -> results.getTitle().contains(query.toString().toLowerCase()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `Stream.of(listRef)` will give back `List<Results>` and there is no method `.getTitle()` on `List`. So this code should throw an error.

Comment: So it should be `listRef.stream()` is what you are saying?

Answer (score 7):

FYI `Stream.of(listRef)` will give back `List<Results>` and there is no method `.getTitle()` on `List`. I think you mean to do `listRef.stream().filter...` instead of `Stream.of(listRef).filter...`

Anyways, this is a standard example which demonstrates that you shouldn't use streams for every operation. You can reduce the streams to:

```
listRef.removeIf(results -> !results.getTitle().contains(query.toString().toLowerCase()));
filteredListIn.addAll(listRef);
```

Note: `.removeIf` will effectively operate on `listRef` so you should `clone` if required.

Comment: Stream.of returns a stream of Results, it's the same as listRef.stream() so I can't see the problem there. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/stream/Stream#of(T...)

Comment: @raven1981 Try it in your ide. `Stream.of(` accepts var-args, not `Collection` or `List`.

Comment: Yep, you're right, didn't notice the input parameters. Anyway, I see easier using the stream() method instead.

Comment: What's the advantage of using this method over using the stream method?

Comment: @Titulum The biggest advantage is that it is concise. Also, Stream API will create additional objects and since this doesn't look like a operation on a big list it will be far more efficient than stream.

Comment: I agree, but based on the example of the OP we can assume that he does not want the original list to be altered, right? When learning Java, you will first encounter the `removeIf` method long before learning about streams, no?

Comment: @Titulum Q1 ans is already mentioned in my post Q2 doesn't make sense to me, what is your point?

Answer (score 4):

`addAll` expects a `Collection` parameter. As long as a stream is not collected, it is of type `Stream` which is independent of `Collection`. Other answers give you a simple solution: collect to a list, then add this list.

I want to mention though that this is not the most efficient solution and introduces quite some memory overhead: the stream is first collected to a new list, then all items of this list are copied to your existing list, and eventually the garbage collector will free the occupied space of the temporary list.

This overhead (allocating memory for the backing array of the temporary list) can be avoided by not collecting the stream, but iterating over its elements with the `forEach` terminal operation:

```java
Stream.of(listRef)
        .filter(results -> results.getTitle().contains(query.toString().toLowerCase()))
        .forEach(filteredListIn::add);
```

If your list is empty to begin with, the best solution is to collect it directly:

```java
final List<...> filteredListIn = Stream.of(listRef)
        .filter(results -> results.getTitle().contains(query.toString().toLowerCase()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or .toUnmodifiableList
```